# How can I stop flux from deploying to my default namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize, fluxcd

I have a Kubernetes cluster setup with [Flux](https://fluxcd.io/). I have an infrastructure folder that has `ingress/base` and `ingress/overlays/development` in it. Hopefully this screenshot helps with the directory structure:

[image: directory structure of kubernetes infrastrcture folder]

Below are my ingress.yaml and kustomization.yaml files from `base`:

```yaml
# ingress.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: user-service
              servicePort: 80
```

```yaml
# kustomization.yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - ingress.yaml
```

In `development`'s folder I have just a kustomization file:

```yaml
# kustomization.yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: development
resources:
  - ../../base
```

When I commit this structure to my flux repository everything successfully reconciles. However, its setting up an ingress in the `default` and `development` namespaces. I want the base folder to be the common config applied to every namespace, I don't want it deployed on its own.

How can I tell Kustomize, or flux, to only use my `base` folders as inputs to the overlays instead of actually deploying the base folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `spec.path` in your [Flux Kustomization](https://fluxcd.io/docs/components/kustomize/kustomization/#generate-kustomizationyaml) component.

```
spec:
  path: "./infrastructure/overlays"
```